# TDS File Replacement for folders not working

Tags: tds, visual-studio

My TDS project has 2  Source Web Projects selected in Properties, WebProj1 and WebProj2 and I want to use TDS File Replacement to deploy some front end folders that to the website root.
After I am doing my settings in VS in the TDS project properties I end up with this:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <Replacement Include="..\WebProj1\Frontend1\">
      <TargetPath>.\Frontend1\</TargetPath>
      <IsFolder>True</IsFolder>
      <IsRelative>True</IsRelative>
    </Replacement>
    <Replacement Include="..\WebProj2\Frontend2\">
      <TargetPath>.\Frontend2\</TargetPath>
      <IsFolder>True</IsFolder>
      <IsRelative>True</IsRelative>
    </Replacement>
  </ItemGroup>
```

But when I built TDS project I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "MakeAbsolutePath" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RelativePath".    GNeCom.Web.Master   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets 334
```

Does anyone what changes are needed in order to have File Replacement working with multile Source Web Projects "attached"?

---

And on same note, if my TDS project has only one Source Web Project selected and I have those settings for File Replacement:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <Replacement Include="..\WebProj1\Frontend1\">
      <TargetPath>.\Frontend1\</TargetPath>
      <IsFolder>True</IsFolder>
      <IsRelative>True</IsRelative>
    </Replacement>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And under the folder `..\WebProj1\Frontend1\` there are couple of sub-folders and files but all files from all sub-folders from `..\WebProj1\Frontend1\` end up all in same place in the target path folder `.\Frontend1\`.

Why is that happening ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, did you ever get to the bottom of this? I've randomly started getting this in a TDS project that was building fine yesterday and it won't go away. I've looked at my TDS project file and it seems ok. I've re-started VS too but no joy.